# Text file with structured data to RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have data in a text file as below and I need to read that to RDD with pyspark so that I can filter it based on column values

```
Property ID|Location|Price|Bedrooms|Bathrooms|Size|Price SQ Ft|Status
1461262|Arroyo Grande|795000|3|3|2371|365.3|Short Sale
1478004|Paulo Pablo|399000|4|3|2818|163.59|Short Sale
1486551|Paulo Pablo|545000|4|3|3032|179.75|Short Sale
1492832|Santa Bay|909000|4|4|3540|286.78|Short Sale
```

suppose I should be able to filter rows where the location is "Santa Bay"

I tried below code but not getting expected result

```py
def getProperiesForLocation(inputRDD, location):
   outputRDD=inputRDD.filter(lambda x:  x[1] == location).map(lambda x: [x[0],x[5],x[2],x[1]])
   return outputRDD                                                                                                                                      

inputRDD = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(lambda x:x.split('|'))                                                                       
location="Santa Bay"
propertiesByLocRDD = getProperiesForLocation(inputRDD, location)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please format your question based upon input and expect output. Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read with `sc.textFile`. This is old and inconvenient API. Use [`spark.read.csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) instead (with `|` as separator):

```py
df = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=True, sep='|')
df.show()

+-----------+-------------+------+--------+---------+----+-----------+----------+
|Property ID|     Location| Price|Bedrooms|Bathrooms|Size|Price SQ Ft|    Status|
+-----------+-------------+------+--------+---------+----+-----------+----------+
|    1461262|Arroyo Grande|795000|       3|        3|2371|      365.3|Short Sale|
|    1478004|  Paulo Pablo|399000|       4|        3|2818|     163.59|Short Sale|
|    1486551|  Paulo Pablo|545000|       4|        3|3032|     179.75|Short Sale|
|    1492832|    Santa Bay|909000|       4|        4|3540|     286.78|Short Sale|
+-----------+-------------+------+--------+---------+----+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the input that you have provided.

[image]

I have copied your input and ran your code and I am getting the correct output.

[image]

Please provide the expected result if this is not what you want.

Comment: Please don't paste your answer as image